# .NET vlc activex fullscreen on second monitor

Tags: .net, activex, fullscreen, vlc

I am making a media player using .NET and VLC activex. The problem I'm running into is when the video is fullscreen, it is always fullscreen on the first monitor even though the application is on the second monitor. Do you have any suggestion how to make it full screen on the second monitor?

Thanks for your help